# Python + Sublime Text 2, right way to put path of file folder

Tags: python, path, sublimetext2

A question on the way of putting the file paths. I am using Python in Sublime Text 2.

Not a new topic but I still don’t get it.

A working fine sample (there a text file aaa.txt in the file folder),

```
file_folder = 'C:\\ABC\\AAA\\'
root, dirs, files = os.walk(file_folder).next()
for txt_file in files:
    with open(file_folder + txt_file) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.rstrip('\n')
            print line
```

It works fine but I need to manually change the “\” to “\” each time if I copy the raw path “C:\ABC\AAA\” from somewhere else.

***When I put it:***

```
file_folder = r'C:\ABC\AAA\'
```

It gives:

```
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

***When I put it:***

```
file_folder = r'C:\ABC\AAA'
```

It gives:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\ABC\\AAAaaa.txt'
```

***When I put it:***

```
file_folder_text = 'C:\ABC\AAA'
file_folder = re.escape(file_folder_text)
```

It gives:

```
StopIteration
```

How can I save the manual changes?

Comment: I think you can just use single forwad slashes `'C:/ABC/AAA/'` but if you copy the path from windows explorer or whatever you have to escape it I guess (some code editors do that for you, or write a macro to replace \ with \\.

Comment: @xander, thank you for the comment. but using forward slashes is another manual change equivalent to changing to "\\".

Comment: Yes that's why I said create a macro in sublime text maybe? I'm no expert when it comes to python or sublime text, but when I use IntelliJ IDEA as my editor it automatically replaces backslahes with double blackslaves when I paste a path into a string (because it's a clever IDE lol). :D

Comment: @xander, thank you for the sharing and suggestion. I just now realised that can use Ctrl + H in Sublime Text to replace. :)

Comment: Well yes simple text replace is part of all code editors I guess, but you can also create a macro and assign it to a custom shortcut or whatever to do that replacement again if you need it often. Just search for "[sublime text macros](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/macros.html)".

Comment: @xander, thanks again! I will be careful with it unless necessary otherwise improper Macro changes something else and caused more manual work. :0